# How do i make that the streamwrite will append the text and not will create a new text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\points.txt");
            if (extendedPoints.Count == 85)
            {
                w.WriteLine("extendedPoints count = 85 , clouds count = 29 | extendedPoints count = 88 , clouds count = 30" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < extendedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                if (extendedPoints.Count == 85)
                {

                    w.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". " + extendedPoints[i].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    w.WriteLine("                                                " + (i + 1) + ". " + extendedPoints[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            w.Close();
```

Once if the count is 85 write the text first time and if its not 85 then add the new text.

This line:

```
w.WriteLine("                                                " + (i + 1) + ". " + extendedPoints[i].ToString());
```

Should be add append to the other text when it was 85.

EDIT**

This is example of how the text file format should look like:

```
extendedPoints count = 85 , clouds count = 29 | extendedPoints count = 88 , clouds count = 30

1. {X=181.8569, Y=172.4}                        1. {X=181.8569, Y=172.4}
2. {X=180.7902, Y=171.8667}                     2. {X=180.7902, Y=171.8667}
3. {X=181.3235, Y=172.1333}
4. {X=180.2569, Y=171.6}
5. {X=179.1902, Y=171.0667}
6. {X=179.7235, Y=171.3333}
7. {X=178.6569, Y=170.8}
8. {X=177.3235, Y=170.8}
9. {X=177.9902, Y=170.8}
10. {X=176.6569, Y=170.8}
11. {X=176.7902, Y=171.4667}
12. {X=176.9235, Y=172.1333}
13. {X=177.0569, Y=172.8}
```

On the left side is when count == 85
On the right side its when its getting to the ELSE part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this instead :

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\points.txt", true);
```

Comment: har07 the problem is that its adding the new text on the bottom after the first text. And i want it to add it near it next to it on the right.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand you, try to use `w.Write` instead of `w.WriteLine`, the later method will add extra new line after the text. Is that what you want?

Comment: har07 updated my question with example of what i mean.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in function to do that. Except you want to read every existing line in text and rewrite that line appended with extra text after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string constructor to make this 85 spaces.

```
string spaces85 = new string(' ', 85);
```

and

```
w.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}",new string(' ', 85),(i + 1), xtendedPoints[i] ) );
```